# Get unique pairs from self-join, plus rows without a match

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, left-join

I'm having a problem with avoiding querying rows that are duplicates except the duplicate values alternate between columns.

I have:

```
select player_standings.player_ID, matched_player.player_ID 
from player_standings 
left join 
(select player_ID, wins from player_standings) as matched_player 
on matched_player.wins = player_standings.wins 
and matched_player.player_ID != player_standings.player_ID
```

Layout of table `player_standings`:

```
player_ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
wins int NOT NULL
```

Say I have the following rows in `player_standings`:

```
player_id | wins
----------+-------
1253      | 1
1251      | 1
1252      | 0
1250      | 0
1259      | 7
```

And I get back:

```
1253, 1251
1252, 1250
1250, 1252  -- reverse dupe
1251, 1253  -- reverse dupe
1259, NULL
```

The result I want is:

```
1253, 1251
1252, 1250
1259, NULL
```

Comment: it's a little unclear what you are asking, giving sample data with desired output is helpful for understanding you well

Comment: @Farhęg +1'd for you

Comment: @unique_id, yea it's really unclear for me, some times I doubt myself while reading such these question, today I started bad I'm a little upset my first answer today down voted without any comment or accepted reason it made me a little upset

Comment: for me the problem is _duplicate values alternate between columns_ I'm not sure maybe my English is very bad, but really as I mentioned sample data and desired output is really helpful

Comment: I gave an example in the question; the query is returning (1253, 1251), (1252, 1250), (1250, 1252), (1251, 1253) ... notice how the 2nd and 3rd, and the 1st and 4th results are the same result except they are flipped? That's what I meant by "duplicate values alternate between columns"

Comment: What's messing this up is this: `I want one of the columns to = None at certain times `. Please clarify. Which column can be NULL in what context?

Comment: Well, at certain times, there will be no 2 rows where player_standings.wins = matched_player.wins; in that case, I want the second column in the result to be null

Comment: Please post your sample data and the desired result that includes "None" case.

Comment: @PM77-1 okay, pretend in the player_standings view, there are 3 rows. Each row has the format: (player_ID serial, wins int ) there is a 3rd column, but I don't use it in the query we're working on so i'll leave it out. the 3 rows in player_standings are: 
(1250, 3), (1251, 3), (1252, 0) I want the result to look like (1251, 1250), (1252, None)

Comment: I updated the question to clarify. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       GREATEST (p1.player_id, p2.player_id) AS id1
     , LEAST    (p1.player_id, p2.player_id) AS id2
FROM   player_standings p1
LEFT   JOIN  player_standings p2 ON p1.wins = p2.wins
                                AND p1.player_id <> p2.player_id;
```

Another way:

```
SELECT p1.player_id AS id1, p2.player_id AS id2
FROM   player_standings p1
JOIN   player_standings p2 USING (wins)
WHERE  p1.player_id > p2.player_id;

UNION ALL
SELECT player_id AS id1, NULL::int AS id2
FROM   player_standings p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   player_standings
   WHERE  wins = p.wins
   AND    player_id <> p.player_id
   );
```

The expression `p1.player_id > p2.player_id` rules out duplicates (except if you have duplicates in the base table).

`UNION ALL` adds every row without a match once.

Comment: @PM77-1: I first thought to extend it to `full join` to include missing matches from both sides, but then I realized it's a self-join, so we don't need that.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either, it returns the same result as the last answer: [(1732, 1730), (1733, 1731), (1730, None), (1731, None)]

Comment: @AdamVanOijen: You need to clarify what can be NULL and what should be in the result ... in your question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Well, at certain times, there will be no 2 rows where player_standings.wins = matched_player.wins; in that case, I want the second column in the result to be null

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I understand the title of this question might be a bit general or hard to understand... Do you think you could edit it so it suits the question better? Thanks.